# Traer usuarios con rol admin Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

quiero traerme los usuarios con rol admin para consumirlo en mi vista echa en vue.
pero no se cual es la sentencia en Eloquent para solo traer usuarios con el role.name 'Admin'. tengo 3 tablas 'User','Role','Assigned_user' siendo esta ultima con la que hago la asignacion.

Tengo en mi controllador en el index esto, pero me trae todos los usuarios.

```
   public function index(Request $request){
    return User::get();
    }
```

Asi se ve mi clase usuario

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;


    public function roles(){
       return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'assigned_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas, he visto que votastes negativamente mi respuesta, por favor, Cambia las imagenes por texto y dame feedback de la repuesta que te he dado. Gracias

Comment: Todo codigo va como texto, porfavor [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/430133/edit) tu pregunta y cambialo

Comment: Ya la cambié amigo, gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado al respecto?

Comment: $relacionEloquent = 'roles'; //Nombre de tu relacion con roles en el modelo User

       return $usuariosAdmins = User::whereHas($relacionEloquent, function ($query) {
            return $query->where('key', '=', 'admin');
        })->get();
Utilizé esta forma

Answer (score 1):

Prueba algo asi:

```
$relacionEloquent = 'roles'; //Nombre de tu relacion con roles en el modelo User

$usuariosAdmins = User::whereHas($relacionEloquent, function ($query) {
    return $query->where('name', '=', 'admin');
})->get();
```

Algo asi deberia de funcionarte.

Comment: Veo que votastes negativamente mi respuesta, que error te da? Asi la puedo ir adaptando

Comment: No fui yo amigo

Comment: De hecho tu respuesta funciona perfecto

Comment: @JuanMFermin si la respuesta te sirvió entonces puedes votarla positivo y/o marcarla como aceptada

Comment: @JuanMFermin Buenas , si ves que te funciono bien dale como respuesta correcta. Asi cualquier otra persona que busque el mismo problema tendra mas facil identificar que esto soluciono tu problema. Me alegro que te sirviera :)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que solo basta con que hagas esto en el controlador:

```
$usuario = UsuarioRol::where('rol_id', 1)->get();
```

Te explico, creas una variable que sea igual a el modelo (`UsuarioRol`) de la tabla relación entre usuarios y roles, y pones donde (`where`) la columna id que relaciona con la tabla de roles (`rol_id`) sea igual al id del rol que desea traer (`1`, en mi caso por que admin = 1), entonces tráigalos (`get()`).

Ya despues para listar los datos, donde sea que lo llames le haces un foreach a la variable (`$usuario as $user`), después a esa variable apuntas a la relación con rol en el modelo de la tabla relación entre usuarios y roles (`$user->rol`) apuntando a el dato del rol que quieres mostrar (`$user->rol->nombre`), el id, nombre, o el campo que quieras, asi:

```
foreach ($usuario as $user){
    $user->rol->nombre);
}
```